# Rails console throwing error for ActiveRecord::Base.connection.table_structure("<table name>")

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying to access table structure through the following command:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.table_structure("projects")
```

The console throws the following error:

> NoMethodError: protected method `table_structure' called for # < ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SQLite3Adapter:0x6559050>

I wanted to know how the Rails console work and what is the reason behind this error? Is there any way I can access table structure through Rails console, instead of switching to Sqlite3 frequently to check the schema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To call the method you want you ca go with:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.send(:table_structure, "projects")
```

But I think a better option would be using [`columns_hash`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaCache/columns_hash) to get the most detailed info about table structure:

> Get the columns for a table as a hash, key is the column name value is
>   the column object.

```
Project.columns_hash
```

Usage: say, you want to get info about `id` column:

```
Project.columns_hash['id']
#=> #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLColumn:0x007fda9e48ce90
# @array=false,
# @cast_type=#<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQL::OID::Integer:0x007fda9bda2e88 @limit=nil, @precision=nil, @range=-2147483648...2147483648, @scale=nil>,
# @default=nil,
# @default_function="nextval('users_id_seq'::regclass)",
# @name="id",
# @null=false,
# @sql_type="integer">
```

There are also [`columns`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/columns/class)

> Returns an array of column objects for the table associated with this
>   class.

and [`column_names`](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/ModelSchema/ClassMethods/column_names):

> Returns an array of column names as strings.

```
Project.columns
Project.column_names
```

See the [full list of methods in documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ModelSchema/ClassMethods.html).

Comment: `NoMethodError: undefined method 'table_structure' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter:0x000000055d9918>` using the send

Comment: @Deepak OP uses SQLite3 :)

Comment: @AndreyDeineko can you please explain the reason behind the console giving protected method?

Comment: @Kartikey I can not explain the reason for sure, because I did not write the code, but it happens when author of the code does not expect anyone to use this method. I really think you would be better of using one of the methods from public API (see methods from my answer and the link I have provided)

Answer (score 1):

You can directly get the structure by just typing model name

In your case

```
Project
```

This will return something like:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base {
          :id => :integer,
        :name => :string,
  :created_at => :datetime,
  :updated_at => :datetime
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain why this approach isn't working?

Comment: It says there in the error itself `table_structure` is a  protected method

Comment: @Kartikey I showed how to call the method you need and also alternatives